# Ubuntu Server 18.10 Splash Screen Customization

Tags: boot, server, grub2, plymouth, 18.10

I can't change the splash screen in Ubuntu Server 18.10.

I've installed `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo` and modified `/etc/default/grub` with the following result:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Then I've updated the grub

```
 sudo update-initramfs -u
 sudo update-grub
```

But the logo doesn't appear.

What am I doing wrong?

This method worked me in Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line will only be used if GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX is not present. So you should set it like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"
```